# @RestController returning blank

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm building my first Spring Boot application. But I can't get my requestMapping controller  answer properly.

This is my main class:

```
package com.hello.world;

@SpringBootApplication 
public class HelloWorld implements CommandLineRunner{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorld.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    ....
}

}
```

And this is my RestController:

```
package com.hello.world.controllers;


@RestController
public class UrlMappingControllers {


        @RequestMapping("/hi")
        String home() {
            return "Hello World!";
        }

}
```

If I take a look at the log I can see the "/hi" mapping:

```
  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/hi]}" onto java.lang.String com.hello.world.controllers.UrlMappingControllers.home()
```

But when I access: http:localhost:8080/hi I get a blank page, I expected seing the "Hello World" text.

Why am I getting a blank page?

--- Edit ----

I've just realised that I am getting the blank page only when I add a cxf service. I think it is because the @configuration annotation on this class:

```
package com.hello.world.helloWorld.configuration;

@Configuration
public class CXFConfiguration {
         @Bean
         public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {
             return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/services/*");
         }

         @Bean(name=Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
         public SpringBus springBus() {
             SpringBus springBus = new SpringBus();
        return springBus;
         }


         @Bean
            public Endpoint endpointGreentingService() {
                EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), new GreetingServiceImpl());
                endpoint.getFeatures().add(new LoggingFeature());
                endpoint.publish("/GreetingService");
                return endpoint;
        }
}
```

Could it be related?

Comment: Add `@ResponseBody` annotation to your `home` method.

Comment: The `@ResponseBody` annotation will not make a difference here, the class is annotated with `@RestController` making the `@ResponseBody` obsolete

Comment: Have you tried making `home()` public?

Comment: Try adding `method = RequestMethod.GET` in your `@RequestMapping` e.g. `@RequestMapping(value = "/hi", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Answer (score -1):

`@RestController = @Controller + @ResponseBody` which means that when you call your api at `http:localhost:8080/hi` the body of the response will contain the result of the `home()` handler, i-e "Hello world".

`@RestController`behind the scene makes Spring MVC uses a Json Message Converter (by default) and all handler methods inside a class annoted with `@RestController` will return a JSON, that is why you do not see your text on your browser.

You can use Postman or ARC to test your app. Some web browsers like Firefox shows JSON directly.

Comment: I've just realised that I am getting the blank page only when I add a cxf service, could it be? I edited the question for more detail

Comment: Yes it could be related as you register a new servlet. The default one `DispatcherServlet' is no longer mapped explicitly. Take a look at your debug web console (press F12) or your IDE's console.

Comment: I'm just curious, you are starting a new project why do you use Apache CXF?

Comment: The only reason why I'm using CXF because the WS i'm going to consume are coded using CXF. Is there a better alternative?